# Running a Macro from a VBS File Giving Error

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, wsh

I am using a vbs code to open and run an Excel macro automatically but getting the following error message:

**Error:** Cannot run the Macro "file location". The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled. 
Code: 800A03EC
Source: Microsoft Excel

**VBS Code:**

```
Dim ObjExcel, ObjWB
Set ObjExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ObjExcel.Visible = True


Set ObjWB = ObjExcel.Application.Run("C:\Automation\TestCasesBackupScript.xlsm!Backup3")


ObjWB.Close False
ObjExcel.Quit
Set ObjExcel = Nothing
```

Macro is enabled and the "Backup3" is the Sub name in a module of TestCasesBackupScript.xlsm file.

Hoping for feedback.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workbook that you're referencing in `Application.Run` has to be open in the context of your `Application` object.  Just open it first, then call it:

```
Dim ObjExcel, ObjWB
Set ObjExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ObjExcel.Visible = True

Set ObjWB = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Automation\TestCasesBackupScript.xlsm")
ObjWB.Application.Run("Backup3")

ObjWB.Close False
ObjExcel.Quit
Set ObjExcel = Nothing
```

Note: If `Backup3` actually returns a Workbook object (which is the only reason to use the syntax `Set ObjWB = ObjExcel.Application.Run`, you'll want to capture that reference in its own variable.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I get the following error after changing the code: "Cannot run the macro 'Backup3'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled. Code: 800A03EC. Source: Microsoft Excel." Error is happening in this line: ObjWB.Application.Run("Backup3").

Comment: It worked after I moved the macro from Module to Microsoft Excel Objects  --> Sheet1(Sheet1). Changed the line that had error before as: ObjWB.Application.Run("Sheet1.Backup3")  - thank you for your feedback, it helped me look to the right place.